# The "sendVerificationCode" method not excuting in firebase

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio

I was working in a project every thing worked fine. while writing the code i put the "sendVerificationCode" metohd and linked it with a button so it could be excuted but it didnt excute when i clicked the button.

also i got this problem that the length of the Prompt phone number should be 10. but when i put the If statmernt it didnt work.

plus i dont get any errors in the log.

** **Here is the code:** **

```
        sPhoneNumber = findViewById(R.id.phoneNumberPrompt);
        Code = findViewById(R.id.codePrompt);
        mVerificationButton = findViewById(R.id.verificationButton);
        mSignButton = findViewById(R.id.signButton);

        mPhoneNumber = sPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
        mCode = Code.getText().toString();

        mVerificationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                if (mPhoneNumber.length() != 10)
                {
                    sPhoneNumber.setError("please make sure your number is right. ");
                    sPhoneNumber.requestFocus();
                }
                else
                {
                    sendVerificationCode(mPhoneNumber);

                    sPhoneNumber.setError("Shit works");
                    sPhoneNumber.requestFocus();
                   // Log.d(Tag, mPhoneNumber);
                }
            }
        });

        mSignButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(mVerificationId ,mCode);
            }
        });

    }

    private void verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(String verificationId, String aCode)
    {
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, aCode);
        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
    }



    public void sendVerificationCode(String phoneNumber)
    {
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
               "+49" + phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
                6,                 // Timeout duration
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
                mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So i found an answer to my qustion for ant body got here for the same qustions.

the problem was that mPhoneNumber string could not be found ethier when i pressed the button to send the verification and when i put the if else statment if was not found so what i did is put the  `mPhoneNumber = sPhoneNumber.getText().toString();` instead from the onCreate method i put it in onClick listner method that was in onCreate method so this is the code

```
 sPhoneNumber = findViewById(R.id.phoneNumberPrompt);
        Code = findViewById(R.id.codePrompt);
        
mVerificationButton = findViewById(R.id.verificationButton);
        mSignButton = findViewById(R.id.signButton);

        
        mCode = Code.getText().toString();

        mVerificationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
                
         mPhoneNumber = sPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
          

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                if (mPhoneNumber.length() != 10)
                {
                    sPhoneNumber.setError("please make sure your number is right. ");
                    sPhoneNumber.requestFocus();
                }
                else
                {
                    sendVerificationCode(mPhoneNumber);

                    sPhoneNumber.setError("Shit works");
                    sPhoneNumber.requestFocus();
                   // Log.d(Tag, mPhoneNumber);
                }
            }
        });
```